# Automate mysql query for numerical $_GET variables

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have this code for mysql query.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `".$data."` 
UNION
SELECT d2.* FROM `".$data2."` d2
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM `".$data."` d1 WHERE d1.id = d2.id)
AND created_at >= NOW() - INTERVAL 35 HOUR
LIMIT 50
";


if (isset($_GET['page-2'])) {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `".$data."` 
    UNION
    SELECT d2.* FROM `".$data2."` d2
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM `".$data."` d1 WHERE d1.id = d2.id)
    AND created_at >= NOW() - INTERVAL 35 HOUR
    LIMIT 50,50
    ";
}


if (isset($_GET['page-3'])) {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `".$data."` 
    UNION
    SELECT d2.* FROM `".$data2."` d2
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM `".$data."` d1 WHERE d1.id = d2.id)
    AND created_at >= NOW() - INTERVAL 35 HOUR
    LIMIT 100,50
    ";
}
```

How yo can see, i have pages example.com/?page-2, example.com/?page-3, example.com/?page-4 and etc.. For every page with numerical get parameter i have separate mysql query.

What is the best way to optimize code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
    <?php

    // If pageNo given
    if(sizeof($_GET) > 0){
        $pageGetKey = array_keys($_GET)[0];
        $pageNo = explode("-", $pageGetKey)[1];
    } else{

        // If no pageNo given
        $pageNo = 0;
    }
    
    
    echo $pageNo;

    $limitMin = $pageNo * 50;
    $limitMax = $limitMin + 50;



    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `".$data."` UNION SELECT d2.* FROM `".$data2."` d2 WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM `".$data."` d1 WHERE d1.id = d2.id) AND created_at >= NOW() - INTERVAL 35 HOUR LIMIT ".$limitMin." , ".$limitMax;


?>
```